# Magento 1.9 Block is not showing the data on front page in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks, frontend, router

Created a module for front-end to show data from custom table but it is showing a blank page.

Here is the config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MageSf_OrderCustom>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </MageSf_OrderCustom>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <magesf_ordercustom>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Block</class>
        </magesf_ordercustom>
        <ordercustom>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Block</class>
        </ordercustom>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <ordercustom>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Helper</class>
        </ordercustom>
    </helpers>

    <models>         
        <magesf_ordercustom>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>magesf_ordercustom_resource</resourceModel>
        </magesf_ordercustom>
        <magesf_ordercustom_resource>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <ordercustom>
                    <table>magesf_ordercustom</table>
                </ordercustom>
            </entities>
        </magesf_ordercustom_resource>
    </models>

    <resource>
        <magesf_ordercustom_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>MageSf_OrderCustom</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </magesf_ordercustom_setup>
        <magesf_ordercustom_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </magesf_ordercustom_write>
        <magesf_ordercustom_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </magesf_ordercustom_read>
    </resource>
</global>       
<adminhtml>
   <layout>
        <updates>
            <ordercustom>
                <file>magsf_ordercustom.xml</file>
            </ordercustom>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
<frontend>    
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <ordercustom>
                <file>ordercustom.xml</file>
            </ordercustom>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <ordercustom>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MageSf_OrderCustom</module>
                <frontName>ordercustom</frontName>
            </args>
        </ordercustom>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
<admin> 
<routers>
     <adminhtml> 
         <args> 
             <modules> 
                <MageSf_OrderCustom after="Mage_Adminhtml">MageSf_OrderCustom_Adminhtml</MageSf_OrderCustom> 
            </modules> 
        </args>
   </adminhtml>        
</routers> 
</admin>
</config>
```

Here is the layout xml file for my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
   <customer_account>        
      <reference name="customer_account_navigation">           
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="ordercustom">
           <name>ordercustom</name>
           <path>ordercustom/customer/view</path>
           <label>Order Attachments</label>
        </action>
      </reference>
   </customer_account>   

 <ordercustom_customer_view> 
    <update handle="customer_account"/> 
        <reference name="content">    
            <block type="ordercustom/customer" name="view.ordercustom" template="ordercustom/customer/view.phtml"/> 
        </reference> 
 </ordercustom_customer_view>
</layout>
```

And My controller file is as follows:

```
<?php


 class MageSf_OrderCustom_CustomerController extends   Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
  {    

  public function preDispatch()
{
       parent::preDispatch();

       if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this))    {
        $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);

    // adding message in customer login page
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
            ->addSuccess(Mage::helper('ordercustom')->__('Please sign in or create a new account'));
    }
  }            
/**
 * View Your Module
 */

public function viewAction() {

  $this->loadLayout();   
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Order Attachments"));
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
  $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
            "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
            "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
       ));

  $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("titlename", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Attachments"),
            "title" => $this->__("Attachments")
       ));

  $this->renderLayout(); 


     }
   } 
?>
```

My Block code is as :

```
<?php


 class MageSf_OrderCustom_Block_Customer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
 {
 public function view()
 {
    echo "Hello World";
    $data = Mage::getModel('magesf_ordercustom/ordercustom')->load();

    $collection = $data->getCollection();
    return $collection;

   }

}

?>
```

And at last my model looks like follows:

```
<?php

  class MageSf_OrderCustom_Model_Ordercustom extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
  {
     public function _construct()
       {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('magesf_ordercustom/ordercustom');
       }
  }
 ?>
```

View.phtml file just printing the whole collection:

```
<?php 

    $collection = $this->view();
        print_r($collection);

 ?>
```

[image]

Can anyone just check where i have done wrong and how i can fix it to show the data from my custom table.

Comment: Please add content for your file **ordercustom/customer/view.phtml** to question.

Comment: Updated the question: i am just printing the whole collection for now

Comment: please make sure you have your phtml file located at **app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/ordercustom/customer/view.phtml** or **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/ordercustom/customer/view.phtml**

Comment: ohhhhh. Got it thanks for getting me out of this... it was misspell in folder name.  "ordercutom"..  thanks

Comment: You're welcome, Please add it as your answer and accept it so it can help others facing similar issue.

Comment: That issue is fixed but now it is printing irrelevant data a huge data.

Comment: You can print only data for your collection. `print_r($collection->getData());`

Answer (score 0):

in your block class change code as below , because in your code you `load` the model and then call `collection`, I think that is not right

```
<?php


 class MageSf_OrderCustom_Block_Customer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
 {
 public function view()
 {
    echo "Hello World";
    $data = Mage::getModel('magesf_ordercustom/ordercustom');

    $collection = $data->getCollection();
    return $collection;

   }

}

?>
```

and also remove below code from your `config.xml`

```
    <magesf_ordercustom>
        <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Block</class>
    </magesf_ordercustom>
```

Comment: Still the same issue. thanks for responding.

Comment: @Shoaib check updated code

Comment: Nope its doing the same. showing the same blank page.  @Murtuza Zabuawala